# Skipping blank entries with a Microsoft Access query when mass emailing?

Tags: vba, ms-access, salesforce

I have a number of Excel sheets that I've imported into Access to prep for importation into Salesforce.com (unifying and mapping different field names to ones SFDC will recognize), and so I can batch email from any one table (Excel sheet) via VBA and Outlook.

I found code that worked perfectly for me here: http://www.jephens.com/2007/05/13/how-to-send-e-mail-from-ms-access-using-outlook/ It works like a charm. I especially love that it sends out the emails one by one instead of as one massive message with everyone BCC'd.

What I'd like to do is alter the code to get more out of this capability, but my knowledge of VBA is very limited.

My problem is two fold. The first is when I have a table that doesn't have an email address for every entry on the list, the query runs into an error. I'm under the assumption that it's a simple matter of dropping in a bit of code that tells the query to skip the missing email address and move onto the next. I don't know VBA that well, however, so I was hoping someone could help me out with what and where I should place the code to make this happen.

The second thing is I have my emails set up so any recipients that receive one can opt out by unsubscribing via a return email. Then I go back to the table (list) I emailed from and drop a "1" in next to their entry under the "Email Opt Out" field I created (SFDC also recognizes this). I want to also be able to query the "Email Opt Out" field and have VBA skip any entries it finds with a 1 so that person doesn't get an email in the future

Hopefully I'm being clear... I'm using Access 2013, and Outlook 2010.

Here's the VBA code behind the 'SendMail' module that makes it all happen when I start the 'SendEMail' macro:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function SendEMail()


Dim db As DAO.Database

Dim MailList As DAO.Recordset

Dim MyOutlook As Outlook.Application

Dim MyMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim Subjectline As String

Dim BodyFile As String

Dim fso As FileSystemObject

Dim MyBody As TextStream

Dim MyBodyText As String



Set fso = New FileSystemObject


' First, we need to know the subject.


Subjectline$ = InputBox$("Please enter the subject line for this mailing.", _

"We Need A Subject Line!")


' If there??s no subject, call it a day.


If Subjectline$ = "" Then

MsgBox "No subject line, no message." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

"Quitting...", vbCritical, "E-Mail Merger"

Exit Function

End If


' Now we need to put something in our letter...



BodyFile$ = InputBox$("Please enter the filename of the body of the message.", _

"We Need A Body!")



' If there??s nothing to say, call it a day.



If BodyFile$ = "" Then

MsgBox "No body, no message." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

"Quitting...", vbCritical, "I Ain??t Got No-Body!"

Exit Function

End If



' Check to make sure the file exists...

If fso.FileExists(BodyFile$) = False Then

MsgBox "The body file isn??t where you say it is. " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

"Quitting...", vbCritical, "I Ain??t Got No-Body!"

Exit Function

End If



' Since we got a file, we can open it up.

Set MyBody = fso.OpenTextFile(BodyFile, ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)



' and read it into a variable.

MyBodyText = MyBody.ReadAll



' and close the file.

MyBody.Close



' Now, we open Outlook for our own device..

Set MyOutlook = New Outlook.Application



' Set up the database and query connections



Set db = CurrentDb()



Set MailList = db.OpenRecordset("MyEmailAddresses")



' now, this is the meat and potatoes.

' this is where we loop through our list of addresses,

' adding them to e-mails and sending them.



Do Until MailList.EOF



' This creates the e-mail



Set MyMail = MyOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)



' This addresses it



MyMail.To = MailList("email")



'This gives it a subject

MyMail.Subject = Subjectline$



'This gives it the body

MyMail.HTMLBody = MyBodyText



'If you want to send an attachment

'uncomment the following line

'MyMail.Attachments.Add "c:myfile.txt", olByValue, 1, "My Displayname"


' To briefly describe:

' "c:myfile.txt" = the file you want to attach

' olByVaue = how to pass the file. olByValue attaches it, olByReference creates a shortcut.

' the shortcut only works if the file is available locally (via mapped or local drive)

' 1 = the position in the outlook message where to attachment goes. This is ignored by most

' other mailers, so you might want to ignore it too. Using 1 puts the attachment

' first in line.

' "My Displayname" = If you don??t want the attachment??s icon string to be "c:myfile.txt" you

' can use this property to change it to something useful, i.e. "4th Qtr Report"



'This sends it!



MyMail.Send



'Some people have asked how to see the e-mail

'instead of automaticially sending it.

'Uncomment the next line

'And comment the "MyMail.Send" line above this.



'MyMail.Display



'And on to the next one...

MailList.MoveNext



Loop



'Cleanup after ourselves



Set MyMail = Nothing



'Uncomment the next line if you want Outlook to shut down when its done.

'Otherwise, it will stay running.



'MyOutlook.Quit

Set MyOutlook = Nothing


MailList.Close

Set MailList = Nothing

db.Close

Set db = Nothing


End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the unwanted records by creating a query as follows:

**Replace:**

```
Set MailList = db.OpenRecordset("MyEmailAddresses")
```

**With:**

```
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("")
qd.SQL = "SELECT * FROM MyEmailAddresses WHERE email IS NOT NULL And Len(Trim(email)) > 0 And OptOut <> 1"
Set MailList = qd.Openrecordset()


' adding them to e-mails and sending them.

Do Until MailList.EOF
  ... your emailing code ...
```

Comment: When I run the macro, I get:

Run-time error '3061':

Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Then it takes me to the code and highlights:

Set MailList = qd.OpenRecordset ()

For the opt out field, I have it labeled as "Email Opt Out". Should I make this one word? For example, "EmailOptOut". Not sure if that's affecting this as well.

Comment: Now I get the Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression. Then it takes me back to the same part of the code: Set MailList = qd.OpenRecordset() Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: I suggest that you instead alter the existing MS Access query called "MyEmailAddresses" rather than defining it in code. Alter the query to exclude the records you don't want. You can check the recordset in MS Access without going anywhere need VBA code. Your VBA just uses the results of this query.

Comment: Also... sick of typing in long paths everytime? you can default the data in your inputbox like this: `InputBox$("Please enter the filename of the body of the message.", "We Need A Body!","C:\A Path\")`

Comment: I took the liberty of naming the Opt-Out field as "OptOut" in my example, so rename this field in the qd.SQL to whatever it is you called it.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. ElectricLlama's suggestion worked best. Eliminating the entries I want via the query and leaving the code alone works just like I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain this is correct because I'm rusty in VBA.
You'll need to make sure the fields are named correctly because I took a guess.

Jump to

```
If (MailList("email") <> "" AND MailList("opt_out") <> 1) Then
```

and make sure that it has the correct fields.

Second,  when you do

```
db.OpenRecordset("MyEmailAddresses")
```

(that bit is before the block of code I pasted) Make sure that query includes the opt out field.

```
Do Until MailList.EOF
    If (MailList("email") <> "" AND MailList("opt_out")) Then
        ' This creates the e-mail
        Set MyMail = MyOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        ' This addresses it
        MyMail.To = MailList("email")

        'This gives it a subject
        MyMail.Subject = Subjectline$

        'This gives it the body
        MyMail.HTMLBody = MyBodyText

        'If you want to send an attachment
        'uncomment the following line
        'MyMail.Attachments.Add "c:myfile.txt", olByValue, 1, "My Displayname"
        ' To briefly describe:
        ' "c:myfile.txt" = the file you want to attach
        ' olByVaue = how to pass the file. olByValue attaches it, olByReference creates a shortcut.
        ' the shortcut only works if the file is available locally (via mapped or local drive)
        ' 1 = the position in the outlook message where to attachment goes. This is ignored by most
        ' other mailers, so you might want to ignore it too. Using 1 puts the attachment
        ' first in line.
        ' "My Displayname" = If you don??t want the attachment??s icon string to be "c:myfile.txt" you
        ' can use this property to change it to something useful, i.e. "4th Qtr Report"

        'This sends it!
        MyMail.Send

        'Some people have asked how to see the e-mail
        'instead of automaticially sending it.
        'Uncomment the next line
        'And comment the "MyMail.Send" line above this.
        'MyMail.Display
        'And on to the next one...
    End If
    MailList.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Sorry about that, like I said, I'm rusty.
I'm not sure why that's happening.  There is definately a do before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the following which does not involve any code and which could enable you to use the very same code that you used initially except to change the name of the table in that code. Let us call your original table "X". Create a select query based on table X, ensuring that all the fields appear in the query. Also ensure that the Email address field appears before (to the left side of)the OptOut field.

In the "Criteria" row of the Email column type: Is Not Null
In the "Criteria" field  the OptOut column type: <>1

Change the query view to "Datasheet". All records (1) that do not have an email address as well as (2) those that do have an email address but have a 1 in the OptOut field will not appear in the datasheet. If you are satisfied with the result, do the following:
Change back to design view, CLICK ON THE "design" tab and next click on "MakeTable" Enter the same name as your original table but add an "X" to it. Please be careful not to enter the same name as your original table. If you make this mistake, your original table will be substituted when the make table query is run. Click Ok in the small window where you entered the table name. Let us call this table name "Y". To run this query, click "DESIGN" and then "Run". You may get a warning message. Respond by allowing the creation of the new table. Save your query

Minimize the query and open the table that it created (Table Y) This table will not have those records that you wanted to be excluded. In the code that worked for you initially, change the table name from X (name of original table) to Y (the name of the new table that was created) in the code you used initially.

ALTERNATIVE OPTION
If you need to delete the unwanted records, there will be no need to make a new table nor to alter your code. To create a query that will delete the unwanted records follow the same steps as those for the Make Table query, but instead of clicking on the "Make Table" icon, click on the "Delete" icon. Save your delete query, close it and do not run it at this stage. Rather first make a copy of your original table, giving the copy another name, the copy to serve you if there may be any problem caused by the delete query. Having made the copy, double click on the delete query and respond to the warning by allowing the deletions. Then examine your original table. The unwanted records should no longer be there. Same have been deleted. Then run your original code without altering it in any way.

Please let me know if this has worked for you. There is a way in which you could automate the process of Making the table or deleting the unwanted records, via a command button.